# Does selecting all tabs include hidden tabs?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Will following the steps below select only the unhidden tabs or hidden tabs also?

Click on the left-most tab (i.e., the tab for the first sheet).  Shift+click on the right-most tab.  You have now selected all sheets.

Finally, click on the triangle to the left of the A column header, above the 1 row label, and below the name box.  You have now selected all cells on all sheets.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any changes to the `Hidden` Tabs!

Comment: Based on my tests, the hidden sheet is not included.

Comment: @Cindy Church  ,,, Yes the Select All ,,, includes both Hidden & Un Hidden Sheets/Tabs ☺  **When you click on the arrow at the left bottom corner to display the list of active sheets, it typically only shows the visible sheets and does not display hidden sheets in the list. This behavior can sometimes lead to confusion because hidden sheets are not directly visible in this list. However, even though hidden sheets are not shown in this list, they are still included when you use the "Select All Sheets" command.**

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, Select-all only selects visible sheets.

Here is what I did:

- Created several sheets
- Marked one sheet as hidden
- Right-click on a sheet and do Select All Sheets
- Shift-click on one of the selected sheets to unselect it
- Right-click one of the selected sheets and select Delete
- Right-click the visible sheet and select Unhide.

Result: All the selected sheets were deleted, the hidden sheet was
not affected.

Comment: ,, I think that your answer is not addressing the issue,,, please go through and better [edit] the post to avoid DOWN Vote ☺

Comment: @RajeshSinha: I think that my answer proves that select-all doesn't include hidden sheets/tabs. Have a second look.

Comment: @harryms   ,,, what steps U have suggested simply helps  to Delete as well Un hide Sheet/Tabs ,,, *but the OP is asking whether the SELECT ALL command includes Hidden Sheet/Sheets or not !!* Where Step no 4 & 5 are irrelevant (about DELETE Sheet). **Actually the Select All Sheet command simply Group the Sheets**   and     *when you select "Select All Sheets" from the right-click menu on any tab in Excel, it does include hidden sheets in the selection. This action selects all visible and hidden sheets in the workbook.*

Comment: @RajeshSinha: Step 4 is required since Excel won't agree to delete all the visible sheets. I admit I'm confused - if the Select-all included the hidden sheet, then why wasn't it deleted together with the visible ones? If the reason is that no operation can be done on a hidden sheet, then I don't see how it can ever be demonstrated that they do get selected. If you could write an answer which demonstrates what you say, I would gladly look at it.